# iPhone: Hide an accessory button in UITableViewCell CORRECTLY based on storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

- **What I want**

  There is a tableview.I just want to hide a UIButtonTypeContactAdd accessory by tapping it in the TableViewCell.
- **My problem**

  When I tapped the accessory button A(which I only tapped in the whole procedure) , it hided correctly. But when I scrolled down the tableview , I found another accessory button B was hided ridiculously. After scrolling **quickly** to the top side of the tableview , the button B guy was there again , meanwhile another button C hided...

  It's pity I can't put images in my post.Hope you can understand what happened.
- **Code**
      tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

  ```
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"All Name Showing Table";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }
  if(!cell.accessoryView){
      UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
      [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      cell.accessoryView = button;
  }
  ```

---

```
    - (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        UITableViewCell *tvc = (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview];
        NSString *peopleTapped = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"you have favored %@",tvc.textLabel.text];
        NSLog(@"%@",peopleTapped);

        sender.hidden = YES;
    }
```

Is all of this because of the mechanism of cell reuse?

Sorry for my poor English.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use table this way. You should have a data model with object which store button accessory button state.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"All Name Showing Table";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
if(!cell.accessoryView){
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryView = button;
}

Model *model = [_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
button.tag = [_array indexOfObject:indexPath.row];
button.hidden = model.hidden;

....
}


- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
 Model *model = [_array objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
 model.hidden = YES;
 [table reloadData];
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: It did works!! Thanks a lot. I created a NSMutableDictionary to save a series buttonModelArray for keys, so I can use indexPath.section and indexPath.row to replace the "tag" in your code. Is this an efficient way? It's my first time to get helped on stackoverflow. ^ ^

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's happening because of cell reuse. You need to be able to keep track of each button in the tableview, probably by aligning it with your data source. This could be easily accomplished by having your cell data source keep track of the state of each button.